# NodeJS ExpressJS How to print API results array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, twitter

I am using twitter API to get tweets then push it into an array. I want to then print the entire array (I just want to know I can pass the values) to my HTML document and display it. Thanks!

Code is below:

```
var express = require("express");
var twit = require("twitter"),
    twitter = new twit({
        consumer_key: 'SECRET',
        consumer_secret: 'SECRET',
        access_token_key: 'SECRET',
        access_token_secret: 'SECRET'
    });

var tweets = [],
    util = require('util');

twitter.stream('statuses/filter', {track: 'love, hate'}, function(stream){
    stream.on('data', function(data){
        if ('delete' in data === false){
            tweets.push(data);
        }
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('Collected ' + tweets.length + ' tweets.');
        stream.destroy();
    }, 1000);
});



var app = express();
var path = require('path');


app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 2400);

function home(req,res){
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", 'text/html');
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
}

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', home);
app.listen(app.get('port'));

console.log('Server running at 2400');
```

Thanks guys. I figured out the rest from here knowing that I need to use Jade:
[Having problems with passing array to jade template in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294541/having-problems-with-passing-array-to-jade-template-in-node-js)

Comment: It looks like you have the hard part done. Now all you have to do is render your tweets array as html. I suggest you take a look at the [Jade Template Language](http://jade-lang.com/) for rendering . Specifically at the [iteration syntax](http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/). Which allows you to iterate over an array and render html for each item in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Jade Template Engine, I'd make only a few small changes in your code then use a Jade template in place of the html file.

**Your code:**

```
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

function home(req,res) {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", 'text/html');
    res.render('index', {tweets: tweets});
}
```

**index.jade**

```
ul
  each tweet in tweets
    li= tweet
```

Here's are the docs that will help you incorporate Jade into your app:

[Using template engines with Express](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)

[Jade Template Engine](http://jade-lang.com/)

[Jade iteration syntax](http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Jade is super helpful, but I want to pass the array into the HTML in order to manipulate and visualize the data with D3JS.

Comment: Never mind. Knowing to use Jade is enough! I figured out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to build a realtime application, from twitter stream data to user web? Using socket.io is the simplest way to emit data to web front-end in realtime

Comment: Not exactly real time. I want the user to type in a #. Then the app will just quickly receive the tweets with that # and pass the array into the HTML to be visualized after with d3js.