# Passing an array to jade rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

So I have a node.js server where I use express and I'm trying to pass an array to jade rendering.

The code in node.js:

```
router.get('/render', function(req, res) {
    var t;
    var combo = {'items': []};

    fs.readFile('ek.txt', function(err, data){
        if(err) {
            return console.error("Error: " + err);
        }

        t = data.toString();

        combo.items = t.split(" ");
        combo.items.pop(); //delete last element which is \r\n
        console.log(combo.items);
    });

    res.render('register', {'items': combo.items}, function(err, html) {
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            res.send(html);
    });
});
```

And here is the jade code:

```
select
    -console.log(items); 
    each item in items
      option= item
```

This should populate my select in HTML but it is empty.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having problems with passing array to jade template in node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294541/having-problems-with-passing-array-to-jade-template-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the correct way to do it, but the problem is that `fs.readFile` is asynchronous. So what happens is that you render an empty array (because the file wasn't read yet).

Possible solution :

```
fs.readFile('ek.txt', function(err, data){
    if(err) {
        return console.error("Error: " + err);
    }

    t = data.toString();

    combo.items = t.split(" ");
    combo.items.pop(); //delete last element which is \r\n
    console.log(combo.items);

    res.render('register', {'items': combo.items}, function(err, html) {
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            res.send(html);
    });
});
```

Or instead of nesting, you can use promises.