# How to render string into javascript in pug

Tags: express, pug

So i am using Express and create an MVC application. I have a list of email that i want to put into javascript variable in the front end and create an auto complete
so currently the controller looks like this:

controller.js

```
res.render('/page',{emails: emails})
```

the `emails` is a JSON structured, can be stringified if needed. and my pug template is as follow

```
div
    input (type = "text" id="suggestion")
    div (class = "custom-suggestion" id="suggestion-list")
```

and at the end, i override custom scripts block with:

```
script.
  var emailList = ///////////i want the email from controller's data
```

How can i achieve this? Any suggestion as long as i can pass the data to the javascript side will be considerable

**EDIT**
To make the code clearer:

app.js

```
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
router = express.Router();
router.get('/',function(req,res,next){
    emails = ['abcd@abc.com','def@def.com','123@123.com'];
    res.render('index', {emails:emails})
})
app.use(router);
```

index.pug

```
extend layout

block content
    h1= title

block scripts
    script
       emails= emails /// not working

       ////////////// how to render this line as 
       ////////////// emails = ['abcd@abc.com','def@def.com','123@123.com']
```

Comment: Try to add what have you tried and what does not work. Add errors, if any. Doesn't `emailList =emails;` work?

Comment: no, ```emailList =emails``` doesnt work, this one is classified project so i can't really share too much, but lemme give a bit additional details in a moment

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20294680. Does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html) to do this:

```
script.
  emails= !{JSON.stringify(emails)};
```

Note that there's a period after the script tag, this tells pug to treat the content inside the tag to be [plain text](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html).  Without that period it will create a script tag then an email tag (`<script><email></email></script>`) which is not what you want here.

Now that you're in plain text mode you can output the template variable into a JavaScript variable using an unescaped interpolation command (`!{...}`) with a stringify inside.